# :after pseudo element doesn't work

Tags: html, css

There are two divs
I intend to make a hover effect over a div. If I hover on div2, it changes its opacity and show some text(here I use :after). But even without hover, the content inside of :after can not be displayed, why?

html:

```
<body>
<section>
<div id='i1'>
    <div id = 'i2'>

    </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

---

css:

---

```
#i1{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156,1.0);
}
#i2{
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
 }
#i2:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
#i2:after{
    content:"hi";
    display: block;
    margin:100px;
    width:100px;
 }
```

---

The "hi" has not been displayed, why :after doesn't work??

---

update: Sorry for my careless, it does show up, just the same color. Acually it's a simplified version, the actual problem is here. see it: a js fiddle link in the comment.

Comment: "hi" does show up.  It's just hard to see because it's black against dark green.  Give it a color of white and you'll see it:  https://jsfiddle.net/jgcap901/

Comment: @RickHitchcock - How to position that "hi" just after the div ends using the after pseudo class and not in the top left corner? Its placing "hi" there because there is nothing inside the div,right?

Comment: Do you mean like this?:  https://jsfiddle.net/ehmwqy3z/  Or like this?:  https://jsfiddle.net/ehmwqy3z/1/

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks a lot ! Actually, it's another issue which doesn't work, I just put a simplified version here. Almost the same problem, but this time I change the color and background color. I'm really appreciate that if you have time to take a look. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/JungleDesigner/p7w9uad1/1/#&togetherjs=JKHVK1m0gd

Comment: I don't have time at the moment, but if you can post it as a new question, I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks all the same

Comment: problem link: https://jsfiddle.net/JungleDesigner/aw5pqndg/2/#&togetherjs=JKHVK1m0gd

Comment: I would recommend posting a brand new question, because it's going to be confusing to people to have to read through your original question and all the comments.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, sure. There are some walkarounds. pretty thanks